# Objective-C Category Performance

Tags: objective-c, performance, design-patterns, code-organization, objective-c-category

If I used categories to break up the implementation of my Objective-C class into multiple `@implementation` blocks, would that make the resulting binary of my iOS app larger or affect performance at all?

Apparently, you can't [Obtain details of categories on a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916829/242933). So, shouldn't the resulting binary be identical with or without categories, assuming all else equal?

#### Background

I have a custom subclass of `UIViewController` that's getting rather complex.

> [iOS Developer Library : Programming with Objective-C : Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2)
>
> As well as just adding methods to existing classes, you can also use categories to split the implementation of a complex class across multiple source code files. You might, for example, put the drawing code for a custom user interface element in a separate file to the rest of the implementation if the geometrical calculations, colors, and gradients, etc, are particularly complicated.

The other nice thing about categories (as compared to `#pragma mark`s, for example) is that Xcode lets you code fold an entire `@implementation` block (but not the code between two `#pragma mark`'s). This is useful if you want to keep categories (optionally folded) in the same file as the main class.

Comment: A category takes a tiny bit of time to load dynamically. No other performance issue.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about code loading time unless you have hundreds of classes. In any case there's nothing you can do about it on iOS, since dynamic code loading is generally forbidden.

Comment: this doesn't have to be about iOS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The linker merges classes and categories when possible. If your class and its categories are all linked into the same executable at build time then the cost is zero.

Answer (score 2):

well categories are loaded dynamically and then 'combined' with the original class. This dynamic loading incurred a little overhead of course but once it is done, method calls to it don't incur any further overhead

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler is anything like c++ then it probably just adds the new functions to the class's virtual method table. I will state that I am making an assumption; however it seems logical since the compiler strictly forbid you from adding instance variables. As far as code organization I think you should be fine according to the documentation linked below:

http://objc.toodarkpark.net/moreobjc.html#756  : section "How Catergories are used"