# Swift extension

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Swift is growing very fast now a days as it has so many cool features for developers. one of the biggest cool feature is `extension`.

1. so adding a so many extension in the project cause any issue of slow
   compiling?
2. does it affect the application overall performance ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598557/objective-c-category-performance

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. Remember: Swift is an Apple product. (Why should it? Parsing an extension does not take any longer than parsing anything else. Most extensions will be already added at compile time to classes and structs.)

Comment: Thanks both of you @JAL the question which you are linking is for Objective-C i know in Objective-C its bit slow if we add so many category because for each category we have to create .h .m file and we can not use the same for another class where in Swift extension we can add it anywhere and same file may contain diffrent class extension.

Comment: extension is one of the base features, it is a compile time feature, it has no runtime (performance) implications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***so adding a so many extension in the project cause any issue of slow compiling?***

Only to the extent that your adding more source code to the project.

***does it affect the application overall performance ?***

No it does not effect the overall performance of the app as an extension is resolved at compile time, not runtime.